# Udpserver doesn't send answer to client

Tags: java, android, udp

The server accept requests from clients but clients don't get an answer from the server, on the server it accepts client authentication but then the client application shows an error message.

The server and client are on the same LAN.

This is the code of server :

```
public class UdpServer extends BaseServer {

public static final int UDP_BUFFER = 10 * 1024; // 10Kb

private static final int NUMBER_USER_INFO_REQUEST_RETRIES = 5;
private static final int SECONDS_TO_CHECK_USER_INFO = 15;

DatagramSocket inSocket = null;
DatagramSocket outSocket = null;

BlockingQueue<DatagramPacket> incomingRequests = null;
BlockingQueue<DatagramPacket> outgoingRequests = null;

HandleIncomingPackets handleIncomingPackets = null;
HandleRequests handleRequests = null;
HandleOutgoingPackets handleOutgoingPackets = null;
HandleUserInfoUpdates handleUserInfoUpdates = null;


public UdpServer() throws IOException {
    this(4445);
}


public UdpServer(int port) throws IOException {
    super();
    inSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    outSocket = new DatagramSocket();

    try {
        serverUserInfo = new UserInfo(UserInfo.SERVER_USERNAME, inSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress(), inSocket.getLocalPort());
    } catch (InvalidDataException e) {
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("oops... initialising serverUserInfo");
    }

    incomingRequests = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    outgoingRequests = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
}

public void run() {         
    handleIncomingPackets = new HandleIncomingPackets();
    handleRequests = new HandleRequests();
    handleOutgoingPackets = new HandleOutgoingPackets();
    handleUserInfoUpdates = new HandleUserInfoUpdates();


    handleIncomingPackets.start();
    handleRequests.start();
    handleOutgoingPackets.start();
    handleUserInfoUpdates.start();

    System.out.println("Server Started");
}


private class HandleIncomingPackets extends Thread {
    private boolean canRun = true;
    private byte[] buf;
    private DatagramPacket packet;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (canRun) {

            buf = new byte[UDP_BUFFER];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

            try {
                inSocket.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    System.out.println("ops... receiving a packet from socket");
                continue;
            }

            incomingRequests.add(packet);
        }
    }

    public void stopHandleMessages() {
        canRun = false;
    }
}

private class HandleOutgoingPackets extends Thread {
    private boolean canRun = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (canRun) {
            DatagramPacket dp = null;

            try {
                dp = outgoingRequests.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) { }


            if (dp == null)
                continue;

            try {
                outSocket.send(dp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    System.out.println("could not send a message: " + dp.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopHandleMessages() {
        canRun = false;
    }

}

private class HandleRequests extends Thread {
    private boolean canRun = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (canRun) {
            DatagramPacket dp = null;

            try {
                dp = incomingRequests.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) { }

            if (dp == null)
                continue;

            String the_msg = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
            the_msg = the_msg.trim();

            String message_type = null;
            try {
                message_type = Procedures.getMessageType(the_msg);
            } catch (XmlMessageReprException e) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    System.out.println("Cannot get the message type :( " + e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }

            if (message_type == null) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    System.out.println("message type is null");
                continue;
            }

            if (Procedures.isLoginMessage(message_type)) {
                manageLoginRequest(dp);
            } else if (Procedures.isRegisterMessage(message_type)) {
                manageRegisterRequest(dp);
            } else if (Procedures.isLogoutMessage(message_type)) {                  
                manageLogoutRequest(dp);
            } else if (Procedures.isUserInfoAnswerMessage(message_type)) {                  
                manageUserInfoAnswer(dp);
            }

            // do stuff
        }
    }

    public void stopHandleMessages() {
        canRun = false;
    }
}

private class HandleUserInfoUpdates extends Thread {
    boolean canRun = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (canRun) {

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date now = c.getTime();

            for (SimpleIMUser simu : registeredUsers) {
                // now - last >= Seconds to check
                // now >= last + seconds to check

                if (!simu.getUser().isOnline())
                    continue;

                c.setTime(simu.last_update);
                c.add(Calendar.SECOND, SECONDS_TO_CHECK_USER_INFO * NUMBER_USER_INFO_REQUEST_RETRIES);
                if (now.after(c.getTime())) {

                    simu.getUser().setOffline();

                    if (DEBUG)
                        System.out.println("HandlerUserInfoUpdates - set "+  simu.getUser() + " offline...");

                    continue;
                }

                c.setTime(simu.last_update);
                c.add(Calendar.SECOND, SECONDS_TO_CHECK_USER_INFO);
                if (now.after(c.getTime())) {

                    sendUserInfoRequest(simu);

                    if (DEBUG)
                        System.out.println("HandlerUserInfoUpdates - send a userInfoRequest... to: " + simu.getUser());
                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(SECONDS_TO_CHECK_USER_INFO * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }

    public void stopHandleMessages() {
        canRun = false;
    }


}

/* 
 * various requests/messages managers 
 * 
 */
private void sendUserInfoRequest(SimpleIMUser simu) {
    UserInfoRequestMessage uirm = new UserInfoRequestMessage(serverUserInfo);

    String uirmXml = null;
    try {
        uirmXml = uirm.toXML();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e1) {
        //unlikely to be here
    }

    DatagramPacket p;
    try {
        p = new DatagramPacket(uirmXml.getBytes(), uirmXml.getBytes().length, 
                                            InetAddress.getByName(simu.getUser().getIp()),
                                            simu.getUser().getPort());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        /* if there's error... nothing to do */
        return;
    }

    outgoingRequests.add(p);
}

private void manageUserInfoAnswer(DatagramPacket dp) {
    String msg = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
    UserInfoAnswerMessage uiam;

    try {
        uiam = UserInfoAnswerMessage.fromXML(msg);
    } catch (XmlMessageReprException e) {
        //nothing to do...
        return;
    }

    UserInfo source = uiam.getSource();

    SimpleIMUser simu = getTheUserFromRegistered(source);

    if (simu == null)
        return;

    simu.getUser().locationData(source.hasLocationData());
    simu.getUser().setAltitude(source.getAltitude());
    simu.getUser().setLatitude(source.getLatitude());
    simu.getUser().setLongitude(source.getLongitude());
    simu.getUser().setIP(source.getIp());
    simu.getUser().setPort(source.getPort());
    simu.getUser().setOnline();
    simu.last_update = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

}

private void manageLogoutRequest(DatagramPacket dp) {
    String request = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
    LogoutMessage lm = null;

    try {
        lm = LogoutMessage.fromXML(request);
    } catch (XmlMessageReprException e) {
        return;
    }

    UserInfo source = lm.getSource();

    SimpleIMUser s = getTheUserFromRegistered(source);

    if (s == null)
        return;

    s.getUser().setOffline();
    s.last_update = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

}

private void manageLoginRequest(DatagramPacket packet) {
    String request = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

    LoginMessage lm = null;
    UserInfo userOfMessage = null;
    String password = null;
    SimpleIMUser s;
    String answer = null;

    InetAddress address;
    int port;

    try {
        lm = LoginMessage.fromXML(request);
    } catch (XmlMessageReprException e1) {
        if (DEBUG) 
            System.out.println("Login message cannot be serialized :(");
    }

    userOfMessage = lm.getUser();
    password = lm.getPassword();

    if (DEBUG) 
        System.out.println("Login message recieved from \"" + userOfMessage.getUsername() +"\"");

    s = getTheUserFromRegistered(userOfMessage);

    if (s == null || (s != null && !s.samePassword(password))) {
        if (DEBUG) 
            System.out.println("Sending REFUSE login to \"" + userOfMessage.getUsername() +"\"");

        try {
            answer = new LoginMessageAnswer(userOfMessage).toXML();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
            if (DEBUG) 
                System.out.println("ops... should not be here :(");
        }

        address = packet.getAddress();
        port = packet.getPort();

        outgoingRequests.add(new DatagramPacket(answer.getBytes(), answer.getBytes().length, address, port));
    } else {
        if (DEBUG) 
            System.out.println("Sending ACCEPT login to \"" + userOfMessage.getUsername() +"\"");

        address = packet.getAddress();
        port = packet.getPort();

        s.getUser().locationData(userOfMessage.hasLocationData());
        s.getUser().setAltitude(userOfMessage.getAltitude());
        s.getUser().setLatitude(userOfMessage.getLatitude());
        s.getUser().setLongitude(userOfMessage.getLongitude());
        s.getUser().setIP(address.getHostAddress());
        s.getUser().setPort(port);
        s.getUser().setOnline();
        s.last_update = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        try {
            answer = new LoginMessageAnswer(s.getUser(), String.valueOf(s.getUser().hashCode())).toXML();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) { 
            if (DEBUG) 
                System.out.println("ops... making a loginAnswer message");
        }

        outgoingRequests.add(new DatagramPacket(answer.getBytes(), answer.getBytes().length, address, port));

        ListMessage listMessage = new ListMessage();
        fillListMessage(listMessage, s);

        try {
            answer = listMessage.toXML();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) { }

        outgoingRequests.add(new DatagramPacket(answer.getBytes(),  answer.getBytes().length, address, port));

    }
}

private void manageRegisterRequest(DatagramPacket dp) {
    String request = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
    RegisterMessage rm = null;
    String answer = null;

    try {
        rm = RegisterMessage.fromXML(request);
    } catch (XmlMessageReprException e) {
        if (DEBUG) 
            System.out.println("Register message cannot be serialized :(");                     
    }

    if (DEBUG) 
        System.out.println("Register message recieved from \"" + rm.getUser().getUsername() +"\"");


    if (registeredUsers.contains(new SimpleIMUser(rm.getUser(), "DUMMY")) || rm.getUser().equals(serverUserInfo)) {
        if (DEBUG) 
            System.out.println("Sending REFUSE register to \"" + rm.getUser().getUsername() +"\"");

        try {
            answer = new RegisterMessageAnswer(rm.getUser(), RegisterMessageAnswer.REFUSED).toXML();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
            if (DEBUG) 
                System.out.println("ops... should not be here :("); 
        } catch (InvalidDataException e) {
            if (DEBUG) 
                System.out.println("ops... should not be here :("); 
        }                       
    } else {
        if (DEBUG) 
            System.out.println("Sending ACCEPT register to \"" + rm.getUser().getUsername() +"\"");

        rm.getUser().setOffline();
        addUserToRegisteredUsers(new SimpleIMUser(rm.getUser(), rm.getPassword()));

        try {
            answer = new RegisterMessageAnswer(rm.getUser(),RegisterMessageAnswer.ACCEPTED).toXML();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
            if (DEBUG) 
                System.out.println("ops... should not be here :("); 
        } catch (InvalidDataException e) {
            if (DEBUG) 
                System.out.println("ops... should not be here :("); 
        }
    }

    outgoingRequests.add(new DatagramPacket(answer.getBytes(), answer.getBytes().length, dp.getAddress(), dp.getPort()));
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    handleUserInfoUpdates.stopHandleMessages();
    handleRequests.stopHandleMessages();
    handleOutgoingPackets.stopHandleMessages();
    handleIncomingPackets.stopHandleMessages();

    inSocket.close();
    outSocket.close();
    super.finalize();
}
}
```

Anything you could do to help or tell me what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: 1. Don't use code formatting for non-code, it's completely unreadable. 2. Programming questions are [offtopic on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 3. If somebody has any questions, he won't send an email but he will comment under your question - but spambots will certainly have some nice ads for you. Don't post your email address publicly.

Comment: ok juste my email for who want the entier application not the code of class